# Can a WiFi modem be directly connected to an android and use the android phone's usb tethering (via an adapter)?

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering, usb-modem

I have an old wifi modem which lacks usb port. I was wondering if we could an rj45 to usb adaptor to use the internet connection from the android device via usb tethering?
Or if there is any other way to achieve the said task, I'd be more than happy to know that.[image: the connectors]

Comment: I am sorry but what is a "wifi modem"? I know DSL or cable or glass-wire modem and I know Wifi router but I never heard of a "wifi modem".

Comment: @Robert we call all these terminal devices wifi modem (technically incorrect, i know). I am sorry, i should've specified that. And my question is regarding any device such with rj45 jack. I wanna know if i can use android phone's usb tethering feature with an rj45–usb convertor.

Comment: Any device will not work, at least the kernel needs to support it. And by the way the picture you have added seems to be an USB cable extender so effectively it is once connected a very long USB cable. Therefore it does not seem to be something you could use with this "wifi modem" ( whatever it is).

Comment: @Robert Sometimes people call modems that also double as WiFi access points "WiFi modems".

Comment: @Robert it's not a simple male to female usb; if you look closely, it is a female rj45 to male usb convertor.

Comment: @robert anyway, that means it's not possible!  :(. I hope someone knowledgeable enough writes such kernels some day.

Comment: @RockPaperLz I know, right. We all grow up calling a lot of stuff wrong or at least partially incorrect names.